# How to stop Text::CSV escaping single quotes?

Tags: perl, csv

*Question is false as it stands - it turns out some intermediate lines in my code are causing the problem. I'll edit it when I find them. Many apologies.*

Suppose the first cell in a CSV has a single quote (') in it. Suppose you read the CSV with Perl's Text::CSV with `$row = $csv->getline($csv_file)`. The first cell will then be in `$row->[0]`. The single quote in it will be escaped.

How do you stop it getting escaped? (I don't mean how do you replace the escaped quote after the fact.) There's doesn't appear to be an option for this in [http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS)

(This issue is specific to Text::CSV. Reading the file with `foreach (<$csv_file>)` doesn't escape 's.)

---

As requested, here's how my code starts (full code to come):

```
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, escape_char => "\\", sep_char => '}', quote_char => '`' });
open my $csv_file, "<:encoding(utf8)", "filepath.csv";
```

Comment: How do you initialize `Text::CSV`?

Comment: Parsing a CSV doesn't cause things to become escaped!!! That's the opposite of parsing.

Comment: @ikegami sure I'll do that :)

Comment: Re "full code to come", A *minimal*, runnable demonstration of the problem, please. That includes providing any necessary data. Especially for this question, it would be good to provide the output you got and the output you expect.

Comment: What on earth does your data look like? `sep_char => '}'` is very strange indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the described behaviour:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA{IO})) {
    say for @$row
}

__DATA__
"a'b",123,x'y
```

Output:

```
a'b
123
x'y
```

I have [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) installed.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot fathom the form of your data that uses a closing brace as a field separator. I suspect you are using the wrong tool to parse your data.

However, I suspect that you are looking at the output of [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) and seeing backslashes in there.

This short program uses your own code and demonstrates what I mean. The output shows the first field as `'aaa\'aaa'` in which `Data::Dumper` has escaped the embedded single quote because it is using single quotes to delimit the string. The output from `Data::Dumper` is intended to be executable using `do` or `eval` so as to reconstruct the original data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, escape_char => "\\", sep_char => '}', quote_char => '`' });

#open my $csv_file, "<:encoding(utf8)', 'filepath.csv';

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {
  print Dumper $row;
}

__DATA__
aaa'aaa}bbb}ccc
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'aaa\'aaa',
          'bbb',
          'ccc'
        ];
```

**Note** that in my opinion [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) is vastly superior to `Data::Dumper`. For the same code it shows the data like this

```
["aaa'aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using Data::Dumper. I'm outputting $row->[0] to a file and running cat on that file. (Only then do I see \' - I don't see it when I `print $row->[0]`.)

Comment: @tog22: And you output to your file using just `print $fh $row->[0]`?

Comment: No, that works fine. Turns out some intermediate lines in my code are the problem - question edited.

Comment: To answer your question about why I use } and ` for sep_char and quote_char, it's because they rarely occur in my input, and I find this the most reliable way of preventing errors, alongside the dozen sequential regexps I'm already having to run on my terrible input file. (SO etiquette question: would answering in this in the main question comments be considered a digression?)

Comment: Using tab as a separator is the usual solution for data like that. Data fields rarely contains the tab character so it is usually safe to use it as a separator. And quoting the fields is unnecessary so the encoding and parsing can be done simply with `join "\t"` and  `split /\t/`.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want to answer in the comments. If you find your own solution to your question then you should post an answer and accept it. Answers to questions in the comments should be posted in another comment beneath. If that answer makes a material difference to the original question, or adds useful information, then you should edit the question as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53917/discussion-between-tog22-and-borodin)